# Certain videos on Roku cut off 10 or so seconds from the beginning

Tags: http-live-streaming, roku, brightscript

I have a Roku channel in beta testing and have seen some peculiar issues with some of our videos. The problem we're seeing is certain, not all, videos have about 10 seconds cut off from the beginning. We're a Television station and all of our content comes from the same production environment but some videos just won't play in their entirety. These videos are edited on Avid systems for what that is worth, has anyone seen this behavior before? Roku Channels are coded in brightscript and that is what I am getting at. Is there something in Brightscript that reads in key frames etc?

Comment: what does this have to do with programming? did you program your channel yourself using a programing language? If not this question is off topic.

Comment: Roku Channels are coded in brightscript and that is what I am getting at. Is there something in Brightscript that reads in key frames etc? So I apologize if this isn't clear.

Comment: @ChanLeonard - if that's your question, please edit it into the question!

Comment: try taking this to Roku Inc developer support forum, http://forums.roku.com/viewforum.php?f=34 - more likely to get response. Also try emailing their dev.support

Comment: Are you using roVideoPlayer of roVideoScreen to play the video in Roku?

Comment: @abhishek - Yes we are.

Comment: @Chan - That's what I am asking which one you are using roVideoPlayer or  roVIdeoScreen. Because you can't use both at the same time for the same video.